django-filters filter by Booleans or None with IN lookup expr
I'm trying to create a filter for DRF viewset that will filter my model field:
    is_claim_submitted = models.BooleanField(
        IS_CLAIM_SUBMITTED_NAME, blank=True, null=True
    )

I've written a filter according to django-filter docs
class BoolInFilter(BaseInFilter, BooleanFilter):
    pass


class DefectFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    is_claim_submitted__in = BoolInFilter(
        field_name="is_claim_submitted",
        lookup_expr="in",
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Defect
        fields = {
            "id",
            "is_claim_submitted",
        }

So I'm trying to filter a queryset by sending request http://localhost:8000/api/v1/defects/is_claim_submitted__in=true,false. Basicly, the values of URI param must be in a list of [True, False, None]. How ever it doesn't filter and it doesn't parse the values to python bools (true -> True). For some reason it doesn't get field_class = forms.NullBooleanField from BooleanFilter, but uses default Field parsing.
I've already checked the MRO, though I still can't manage to figure out why my code doesn't work.
The problem is precisely with BooleanFilter, as all the same but with NumberFilter and ids works fine.
Is there a mistake in my code or is there a better way to implement such a filter?

I'm not familiar with DRF but for a normal queryset, null (or None)  is not a value. So you have to filter with for example Q(field=True)|Q(field__isnull=True) to pull out True or is null. I can't remember whether exclusion works to get the same  .exclude(field=False) but I feel a nagging doubt about this.

@nigel222 this is what should parse bool values in BooleanFilter -> forms.NullBooleanField so null should be converted to None. However my code reaches this method with value=None instead of True or False and I don't know why:
def to_python(self, value):    if value in (True, "True", "true", "1"):         return True    elif value in (False, "False", "false", "0"):        return False    else:        return None

Well after some digging, I finally came to a solution, though I don't like it.
If someone comes up with a better one please share.
I created three classes overwriting initial methods.
This is my filter class. It needs to filter

?is_claim_submitted=true,false,null

class DefectFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    is_claim_submitted = BooleanInFilter(
        field_name="is_claim_submitted",
        lookup_expr="in",
    )


    class Meta:
        model = Defect
        fields = {
            "is_claim_submitted",
        }

Next we are going along the MRO. BooleanInFilter inherits from BooleanFilter which just specify the field_class under the hood.
class BooleanInFilter(BaseInFilter, BooleanFilter):
    field_class = MultipleNullBoleanField

    def filter(self, qs, value_list):
        ...filtering logic

So I change it in order to rewrite the field_class' method value_from_datadict. This method extracts data from GET params and serialize them into python values. However the original method, despite the inheritance from BaseInFilter (which should split values by comma), first trys to serialize value and only then to split it. And I needed it the other way: first split then serialize each one. That is why I implemented the next class that just puts split function at top and adds a loop over the splitted values.
class MultipleNullBoleanField(forms.NullBooleanField):
    widget = MultipleNullBooleanSelect

class MultipleNullBooleanSelect(NullBooleanSelect):
    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        values = data.get(name, "").split(",")

        parsing_dict = {
            True: True,
            "True": True,
            "true": True,
            False: False,
            "False": False,
            "false": False,
            "null": None,
        }

        values_list = []
        for value in values:
            parsed_value = parsing_dict.get(value, "")
            if parsed_value == "":
                continue
            values_list.append(parsed_value)

        if values_list is not None:
            if isinstance(values_list, list):
                return values_list
            return values_list.split(",")
        return None

I suppose there might be a better solution, but after three days of digging I haven't found anything at least similar to what I needed.
